# 'NoneType' object is not iterable using json file

Tags: python, json

I am facing this error `'NoneType' object is not iterable` when iterateon Json file.

**My code:**

```
import nltk
import json
from nltk import word_tokenize
with open('full_format_recipes.json', 'r') as myfile:
data=myfile.read()
obj = json.loads(data)
result=[]
for a in obj:
    for b in a.get("ingredients"):
        print(type(b))
        text = word_tokenize(b)
        res = nltk.pos_tag(text)
        res = [t for t in res if isinstance(t[1],list) not in ["NN", 
         "NNS","NNP", "NNPS"]]
        print(res)
        result.append(res)
```

**Error:**

```
for b in a.get("ingredients"): TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Comment: So it's likely that there is no key 'ingredients', hence the error, did you check this?

Comment: can you explain/paste the file contents here?.

Answer (score 0):

The dict [`get` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) returns `None` when a key is not found in the dictionary and a default is not given.

So you either need to

- check, as EdChumif says, whether each `a` in `obj` actually has that key
- check that you're correctly traveling the scturcture of the decoded json object
- provide an empty iterable as a default for the `get` function.

We can't give you a more specific answer without seeing a sample of the file you're working with.

Comment: i will send you json file

Comment: but where i send you my json file

Comment: @ShahWajahat We don't really need the full file, but we need a small sample to see its structure. If there is sensitive/private information within you can change that info by had and add that sample to your question by edditing the question itself.